# Tight VNC saveed connections not loading

Tags: vnc

I'm getting an odd error when I try to connect to a machine through tight VNC using a saved connection.

The error reads "Error in tightVNC viewer: the connection parameters (host, port, socket, gates) is empty"

Opening the VNC file in a text editor shows the parameters are set correctly.

The saved vnc files do work on a separate setup in the same office.

I have tried a clean reinstall of TightVNC and all the agents on the would be connections.

Any thoughts or better places I could look?

Answer (score 6):

What solved the problem for me was fixing these registry keys:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\tvnviewer.exe\shell\open\command`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\vnc_auto_file\shell\open\command`

Your path to the viewer may be different. The trick for me was adding the -optionsfile.
It needs to be "C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe" "-optionsfile=%1"

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore. As of v.2.8.59 the registry key is already set as described here, but it still fails. Even calling it from command line, i.e., `tvnviewer -optionsfile=test.vnc` results in an error. Quite a few people reporting this bug in their tracker at https://sourceforge.net/p/vnc-tight/bugs/. I still +1 this as it helped me the last time around.

Comment: Right after adding my comment I tried `tvnviewer "-optionsfile=test.vnc"` from the command like and what do you know? It worked! Double-clicking a .vnc file is still broken though, but at least the CLI works.

Comment: And figured it out. Turns out there are two separate keys. One has the correct value as shown in this answer; the other one is missing the `-optionsfile=` bit and doesn't work. I'll update this answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem as follows:

1. Copy the .vnc file (e.g. DOCU-PROIST.vnc) to client installation directory e.g. C:\Program Files\TightVNC
2. Create a shortcut of the tvnviewer.exe file on the desktop.
3. Right click on the shortcut and go to properties.
4. Edit the "Target" field to "C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe" -optionsfile=DOCU-PERIF.vnc

By double clicking on the shortcut the connection opens using the DOCU-PERIF.vnc file

Answer (score 0):

In my `.vnc` file, I just had to remove the `vnc://` protocol from the host field, and everything worked fine.